# How to store result of diff in Linux

Tags: linux, file, diff

How to get the result on another file after applying diff to file A.txt and B.txt.

Suppose File A.txt has:

```
a
b
c
```

File B.txt has:

```
a
b
```

on running

diff A.txt B.txt
It gives result as c, but how to store it in a file C.txt?

Comment: `diff A.txt B.txt > C.txt`  - surprised that you did not read up on basics. Anyway, very likely that your question will be voted to close.

Comment: ya close it...who cares....i got my answer....

Comment: I found this useful - thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `diff` utility produces its output on standard output (usually the console). Like any UNIX utility that does this, its output may very simply be redirected into a file like this:

```
diff A.txt B.txt >C.txt
```

This means "execute the command `diff` with two arguments (the files `A.txt` and `B.txt`) and put everything that would otherwise be displayed on the console into the file `C.txt`". Error messages will still go to the console.

To save the output of `diff` to a file and *also* send it to the terminal, use `tee` like so:

```
diff A.txt B.txt | tee C.txt
```

tee will duplicate the data to all named files (only `C.txt` here) and also to standard output (most likely the terminal).

Comment: is it possible to output the diff into a file as well as to the screen simultaneously? This is particularly related to diff of folders using `diff -rq`, which could sometimes take a long while.. and it would be useful to see the actual output on the screen as well.

Comment: @alpha_989 Absolutely:  `diff A.txt B.txt | tee C.txt`.  `tee` will duplicate the data to all named files (only `C.txt` here) and also to standard output.

Answer (score 6):

Using `>` you can redirect output to a file. Eg:

```
    diff A.txt B.txt > C.txt
```

This will result in the output from the diff command being saved in a file called C.txt.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Output Redirection.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

> diff file1 file2 > output

will store the diff of file1 and file2 to output

Answer (score 0):

There are some files that `diff` may not do well with the output, like block special files, character special files, and broken links. The output due to differences with these may go to standard error.

Interestingly, when I redirected standard error, I still missed some things:

```
diff -qr <DirA> <DirB> 2>&1 > mydiff.txt
```

The only way to see the results of everything was to:

```
diff -qr <DirA> <DirB> |tee mydiff.txt
```

I was comparing the results of a live-cd mounted directory after copying to an external HD