# Idea - save diff result

Tags: intellij-idea, diff

I can use diff tool in Intellij Idea. I would like to export (save diff result).
How?

So far, I would make a screenshot of each diff part, and save it and then build a large picture of smaller diff parts.

Linux diff can export results.
[How to store result of diff in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732545/how-to-store-result-of-diff-in-linux)
However, my machine is Windows, so I cannot use Linux tool.

[image: Idea diff tool]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of saving diff results to a file. Three is somewhat related request - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217505

You can create a patch from Local Changes though.